# Change KNOPPIX 7.0.4 boot

Tags: linux

I would like to know how can i make knoppix enter the Desktop directly without asking for a login or to chose from a menu on the boot like it is right now .

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Knoppix is a live CD bootup, if you have installed it from the live CD and now getting a log in prompt

Go to:
KDE button
system settings
Last set of options administration and look for/click o Login screen 
Last tab of login screen is convenience

On the left it has enable auto login and on the right enable passwordless login

Comment: The version i have dont have KDE or atleast do not use it by default when i chose startx or startx full session by default he starts the LXDE

Comment: is there a reason you must use this version of knoppix ? if not and if you have a blank cd and cd burner then download and burn either a later version of knoppix or go for kubuntu cd download, most distros give you the option to try out i.e. like live cd boot up and try it out before installing.

Comment: just to point out regardless of distro or what desktop manager it comes with, the system will and can run other desktop managers.

Comment: regardless of distro or what desktop manager it comes with, the system will and can run other desktop managers. yum search desktop |grep manager or apt-cache search desktop|grep manager - this will show all the types available for install.  This being a boot up image may not be good advice since you really need an installed and running version of a Linux desktop to be able to keep it permanent. You could Linux live CD persistence if your eager for a change and wish to keep it as bootup http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Linux_distributions